# Transforming a parenthesized string of numbers to a tree

Tags: parsing, haskell, tree

I am developing a function to transform a parenthesized string of numbers to a tree. So, for example,

```hs
treeFromString "((1)((3)(4)))" == Right (Nd (Lf 1) (Nd (Lf 3) (Lf 4)))
```

This is my attempt. I am assuming a well-formed string to tackle an easier problem, but the type signature should be `Either String (BinL' Int)`.

```hs
import Data.Char

data BinL' a = Lf a | Nd (BinL' a) (BinL' a) deriving Show

treeFromString :: String -> BinL' Int
treeFromString [] = undefined
treeFromString ('(':cs) = case span isDigit cs of
                            ("", remaining) -> treeFromString cs
                            (digits, remaining) -> Nd (Lf (read digits)) (treeFromString remaining)
```

What’s value should I return when the parameter passed is an empty list ?

Is my general approach a sensible one to accomplish what I want ?

EDIT:

There is a complementary function which converts a tree to a parenthesized string. The function I am developing should perform the opposite transformation. Example:

`showBinL' :: Show a => BinL' a -> String`

```
showBinL' (Nd (Lf 1) (Nd (Lf 3) (Lf 4)))
"((1)((3)(4)))"
```

Comment: To what would `((1)(2)(3))` parse?

Comment: That's is a good question, @willeM_VanOnsem. I can't see what should be the output in that case. I don't know the person who created that exercise to ask, unfortunately.

Comment: I can't map your example to a binary tree, I think.

Comment: so that would be aprsing error then? Just to make sure I understand the problem.

Comment: Yes, @willeM_VanOnsem. I think you are right. That would be a parsing error.

Comment: I'll edit to add extra detail

Comment: `""` aka `[]` does not seem a well formed string given your definition of `BinL'` so your assumption is wrong.

Comment: Within the rules of that game, are you at liberty to define the tree structure you want, or is it necessarily/mandatorily that `BinL'` thing ?

Comment: I actually would sugest an LR-approach rather than the LL parser you are building right now, which might require some "lookahead"/.

Comment: Yes, that is right BinL' is required, @jpmarinier.

Comment: What do you mean by LR-approach @willeM_VanOnsem ?

Comment: @F.Zer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_LR_parser it basically works "bottom-up" with a stack, instead of top-down (which is essentially what an LL-parser does).

Comment: I do not have the current knowledge to understand that. Could you or someone give me some pointers about how to approach this problem, if possible ? I am not sure how to implement an LR parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care much about efficiency, I recommend the standard beginner-friendly approach:

> A parser for things
> is a function from strings
> to lists of pairs
> of things and strings.
> -- Graham Hutton

And, you're in luck: the language-standard `Read` class puts its parsers in this framework.

```
reads :: Read a => String -> [(a, String)]
```

So, if you're building up machinery for working with that kind of type smoothly, then you can cleanly slot in `reads` when you need to read a number, and in fact can even generalize from reading trees of numbers to reading trees of any `Read` instance.

So here is the type I recommend you try to implement first. If you must have a specific type, you can write a small wrapper around it afterwards to convert.

```
treeFromString :: Read a => String -> [(BinL' a, String)]
```

In the common case, the resulting list will have one element if the string parses successfully, containing the tree and the suffix of the string that wasn't parsed yet (if any); if parsing fails, the resulting list should be empty.

Before you sit down to start writing parsing code, it's often a good idea to try writing down the grammar first. Here's my guess at a sensible grammar: a tree is a pair of parentheses containing either two children in sequence or the value of a leaf. Like this:

```
T ::= '(' T T ')'
    | '(' <leaf> ')'
```

One implementation plan would be to build a small library of parsers that can be combined to produce this grammar. I recommend the following set:

- A parser that consumes a single character, and doesn't return any interesting data.

  ```
  char :: Char
       -> (String -> [((), String)])
  ```
- A way to sequence two parsers, i.e. parse first one thing, then use whatever remaining text there is from the first parser to parse the second thing.

  ```
  andThen :: (String -> [(a, String)])
          -> (String -> [(b, String)])
          -> (String -> [((a, b), String)])
  ```
- A way to alternate two parsers, i.e. try both parsers on the same input, returning any results either one gives.

  ```
  orElse :: (String -> [(a, String)])
         -> (String -> [(b, String)])
         -> (String -> [(Either a b, String)])
  ```
- A way to transform the data returned by a parser when it succeeds.

  ```
  finally :: (String -> [(a, String)])
          -> (a -> b)
          -> (String -> [(b, String)])
  ```

With those in hand, you can transliterate the grammar above into a parser quite directly:

```
t :: Read a => String -> [(BinL' a, String)]
-- T ::=       '('           T           T                ')'
t      = (char '(' `andThen` t `andThen` t `andThen` char ')' `finally` \(_, (l, (r, _))) -> Nd l r)

--     |              '('           <leaf>               ')'
       `orElse` (char '(' `andThen` reads `andThen` char ')' `finally` \(_, (v, _)) -> Lf v)
```

Comment: Thank you so much again, Daniel. +1 I will look into that.